# getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

please help me with this problem
my app crash when I try to run this code
I have attached a screenshot of my logcat
I have implemented source code from this link for the country code spinner
https://github.com/joielechong/CountryCodePicker
I am trying to make an activity to get user phone number and save the data entered by user to firebase Firestore

[logcat screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dqwt.png)

my activity java code on android studio

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.rilixtech.CountryCodePicker;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class introPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    CountryCodePicker ccp;
    EditText phoneNumber;
    String countryName;
    String phoneNum;
    int countryCode;
    FirebaseFirestore db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ccp = (CountryCodePicker) findViewById(R.id.ccp);
    phoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberEditText);
    phoneNum="";
    countryCode = 0;
    countryName="";
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro_page);




    if(mAuth == null) {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    if(db == null) {
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this));
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"long press to sign out",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        mAuth.signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(introPage.this, LoginActivity.class));
        finish();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}



public void getPhoneDetails(View view){

    if(phoneNumber.getText().toString().length()==0){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please key in phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }else{


        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String id = "";
        id = currentUser.getUid().toString();

        countryName = ccp.getSelectedCountryName();
        countryCode = ccp.getSelectedCountryCodeAsInt();
        phoneNum = phoneNumber.getText().toString();

        Map<String, Object> infoUpdate = new HashMap<>();
        infoUpdate.put("country", countryName);
        infoUpdate.put("countryCode", countryCode);
        infoUpdate.put("phoneNumber", phoneNum);

        db.collection("users").document(id).update(infoUpdate)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String storeData = "done intro";
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("doneIntro",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            fOut.write(storeData.getBytes());
                            fOut.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        startActivity(new Intent(introPage.this,barcodePage.class));


                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("TAG", e.toString());
                    }
                });



    }


}





}
```

Comment: At which line of code are getting that error?

Comment: I am not sure about the exact line, but confirm in the "getPhoneDetails" function

Comment: That error for sure points to a line of code, which is?

Comment: No, @AlexMamo. The error doesn't point to a line of code. That's a logcat error.